# Pandas: replace cells from other pd.Series based on subcondition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with two columns 'a' and 'b'.

I have another pandas series which consists of the 'b' values. The **index** of this series are the `a` values from `df`.

Importantly, the series is **NOT** of the same size as the dataframe. It only has about half the amount of rows.

What I want to do is simply **replace** the `b`-values in `df` if that value is **less** than the corresponding `b`-value in the pandas series.

I've tried so many things, but keep running into errors.

For example, if the **dataframe** has df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b' : [1,2,3,4]})

```
    a    b
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   4    4
```

and the pandas series has `data = {1: 0.5, 4: 5}`, then the updated dataframe should have

```
    a    b
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   4    5
```

As you can see, only the value with index `4` got updated, since `5 > 4`.

Comment: Why don't you add some sample data so we can try ourselves.

Comment: Done! I don't know how to format it nicely though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, using your example Series and DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

sr = pd.Series({1: 0.5, 4: 5})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df['b'] = df.apply(lambda row: sr[row['a']] if (row['a'] in sr.index) and (row['b'] < sr[row['a']]) else row['b'], axis=1)
```

This works by applying an anonymous function (defined by the lambda operator) to each row of your DataFrame and checking if the a-value of that row exists in the series index and if the b-value is greater in the series than in that row of the DataFrame. On that basis it choses wether to take the value from the Series or keep that which is already in the DataFrame.

A KeyError that would normally occur when you try to look up a value in the Series for an index that doesn't exist is avoided by placing the `(row['a'] in sr.index)` statement first in the if conditional. Since the second part of the conditional after the `and`is only evaluated if the first part evaluates to `True`, the KeyError is avoided for such cases.

Edit:

Since the lambda function is a hard to read oneliner, you can also do it more verbosely by defining your function explicitly:

```
def comparison(row):
   if (row['a'] in sr.index) and (row['b'] < sr[row['a']]):
      return sr[row['a']]
   else:
      return row['b']

df['b'] = df.apply(lambda row: comparison(row), axis=1)
```